# Draw line and add collider to it

Tags: unity-game-engine

I would like to know how can I draw a line that contains a collider. I'm trying to do something like that:

[image]

I followed this website tutorial:
https://unitycoder.com/blog/2017/09/23/drawing-2d-lines-and-adding-collider-to-it/

But it didn't work as I expected, the line is being drawn, but the object that should collide with the line, do not collide.

What do I need to change on my code?

Code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DrawLine2D : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    protected LineRenderer m_LineRenderer;
    [SerializeField]
    protected bool m_AddCollider = false;
    [SerializeField]
    protected EdgeCollider2D m_EdgeCollider2D;
    [SerializeField]
    protected Camera m_Camera;
    protected List<Vector2> m_Points;


    protected virtual void Awake ()
    {
        if ( m_Camera == null ) {
            m_Camera = Camera.main;
        }
        m_Points = new List<Vector2> ();
    }

    protected virtual void Update ()
    {
        if ( Input.GetMouseButtonDown ( 0 ) )
        {
            Reset ();
        }
        if ( Input.GetMouseButton ( 0 ) )
        {
            Vector2 mousePosition = m_Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint ( Input.mousePosition );
            if ( !m_Points.Contains ( mousePosition ) )
            {
                m_Points.Add ( mousePosition );
                m_LineRenderer.positionCount = m_Points.Count;
                m_LineRenderer.SetPosition ( m_LineRenderer.positionCount - 1, mousePosition );
                if ( m_EdgeCollider2D != null && m_AddCollider && m_Points.Count > 1 )
                {
                    m_EdgeCollider2D.points = m_Points.ToArray ();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected virtual void Reset ()
    {
        if ( m_LineRenderer != null )
        {
            m_LineRenderer.positionCount = 0;
        }
        if ( m_Points != null )
        {
            m_Points.Clear ();
        }
        if ( m_EdgeCollider2D != null && m_AddCollider )
        {
            m_EdgeCollider2D.Reset ();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Since you are following the tutorial, you should probably start by looking for discrepancies between both the source codes. For example, you've missed out the error catching from the original which would probably tell you why it's not working.

Comment: I removed some code from the original because I don't want to generate a new line renderer and collider, I'm setting both directly. I tried to run the original code, without changes, and the output was the same

Comment: @A.BC try removing `m_AddCollider` from both of your if checks? if you are just updating points that probably shouldnt be there, since you are never setting it to true.